# Convert expanded boolean function into a switching matrix

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, boolean-algebra, matrix

I am given a boolean function `f(x)` that I have to develop them according certain variables, let's call them `a0` and `a1`, using Boole's Expansion Theorem. From the result I have to construct a "switching array". I have developed my function according to the variables but I'm not sure how to develop them into a switching matrix.

PS - I can't post the function because it's a homework exercise but I would just like some general help in deriving a switching matrix from a function

Comment: What is a "switching array/matrix"? Are you talking about a truth table?

Comment: You can post homework questions but you have to demonstrate significant effort in solving the problem so that anyone making an answer can understand both where you are stuck and why you are stuck.

Comment: @Andyaka, sometimes the Home Work might be copyrighted to prevent students from seeking help from homework-answering sites like Chegg

Comment: Maybe helpful if you quoted what your text book / lecture notes say about "switching array". And show your work so far.